# Difference between calendar.MINUTE and calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) in Android

Tags: java, android, calendar

I have two `Calendar` variable named as `calendar1` and `calendar2` 
 that has some Calendar value stored in it.

I want to compare the `MINUTE` value from those variables.

I found two methods but I want to know what is the difference and which one is correct.

```
if(calendar1.MINUTE == calendar2.MINUTE)
```

and

```
if(calendar1.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == calendar2.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
```

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`calendar1.MINUTE` means you're accessing one of the `static` constant of `Calendar` class. This is same as `Calendar.MINUTE`.

Should not access a constant field using an object (E.g. calendar1.MINUTE).

When you call `calendar1.get()` you need to pass which field of Calendar you want to retrieve, either `MINUTE`, `HOUR`, `MILLISECOND`, `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY_OF_MONTH`

About this line

```
if(calendar1.MINUTE == calendar2.MINUTE)
```

You're just comparing both constants, this will always return `true`

The second line is correct

```
if(calendar1.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == calendar2.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
```

Comment: Answer that I was looking for. But what is the significance of calendar.MINUTE if it always returns the same value (being a static field)?

Comment: Just use **C**alendar.MINUTE.

Comment: @SteveBenett I did and its not working as expected. The `if` is returning `true` even when minutes are not same. (Edited)

Answer (score 1):

`MINUTE` returns the minute number as an int : E.G (13:04 -> MINUTE is 4)

`get(int field)` - > returns the value of the given field after computing the field values by calling `complete()` first.

`complete()` ->computes the time from the fields if the time has not already been set.

Comment: Which one should be used when and why?

Comment: You should use the second with get();because MINUTE is static final Integer ; and it's bad practice to call static members from an instantiated object.

Answer (score 1):

Okay Here is an answer of your question.

**Calender.MINUTE : -** It gives minutes without zero. If the minutes are in between 1 to 9.

e.g : I have time on my device 12:09 but its gives as 12:9

**cal.MINUTE  : -** This is a static final Integer for use in **Calendar** method calls.

And It is bad practice to call **static** members from an instantiated object.

So best way to get correct values by `cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);` .

Comment: Returning without zero isn't the only difference i guess. Gleen's ans is correct. It is always returning true.

Comment: @SrujanBarai : His answer is absulately correct. +1 for him.